# Redownloading iWork for iPad apps without paying for them

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore, iwork

I bought an iPad Air 2 fourteen months ago. Recently I reset my iPad and now Pages, Keynote, and Numbers are not free — they ask for payment. How can I download them again without paying?

I tried to switch my iPad off and on and I tried another Apple ID, but neither of those worked. My device is fully upgraded to iOS 10.2.

Comment: Did you try with the Apple ID you initially used when setting up the iPad/logging into the Store?

Comment: Do they show up in the Purchased tab?

Comment: Also, have you ever synced your iPad to iTunes?

Comment: Just to verify, you bought the iPad new or was it already set up by someone else?

Comment: To clarify all the above comments - all apps [as well as the device itself] on iOS belong to the Apple ID that first downloaded them. if you have multiple IDs [not wise] then you need to sign in to the one that first purchased the app.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your iPad and downloaded these apps, the iPad would have asked you to sign in to iTunes & App Store, then registered the apps to this Apple ID as it was the first used to download them. You must use this **same** Apple ID to re-download the apps later.